# Speed up SQL Query, has worked

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have this query

```
SELECT distinct(season) as seasons,
        s.name as seriename,
        c.content_digest,
        c.sub_category_id,
        c.source_url,
        c.synopsis,
        c.short_synopsis,
        c.title,
        c.duration,
        c.subtitle_url,
        c.logo_url,
        c.provider_id,
        c.event_date,
        c.start_time,
        c.live,
        c.seriesid as cSerieId,
        c.episode,
        c.season,
        c.content_id FROM content c
        INNER JOIN provider ON provider.id = c.provider_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN serie s ON s.seriesid = c.seriesid
        WHERE live = '0' AND c.version >= provider.version
        ORDER BY seriename DESC, title
        DESC
        LIMIT 0, 18446744073709551615;
```

Which has been indexed and somewhat optimized to deliver results fast (it has delivered 44000 rows in 0.3 sec). 
For some unknown reason, which grinds my gear, it is no longer 0.3sec fast, its 2.5 sec fast.

Here is the EXPLAIN for above SQL

```
1   SIMPLE  provider    index   PRIMARY,provider_id_idx,provider_version_idx    provider_version_idx    5       16  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort

1   SIMPLE  c   ref c_providerid_idx,c_live_idx,c_version_idx   c_providerid_idx    5   provider.id 3179    Using where

1   SIMPLE  s   ref seriesid_idx    seriesid_idx    97  c.seriesid  1
```

As i understand, it is using its indexes, but still 2.5 sec.. 
I've googled query cache, activated it, tried to tweak it, but still, 2.5 sec.

Any advice? 
Ill post more info if you need...

**Final result**

```
SELECT s.name as seriename, 
            c.season as seasons,
            c.content_digest,
            c.sub_category_id,
            c.source_url,
            c.synopsis,
            c.short_synopsis,
            c.title,
            c.duration,
            c.subtitle_url,
            c.logo_url,
            c.provider_id,
            c.event_date,
            c.start_time,
            c.live,
            c.seriesid as cSerieId,
            c.episode,
            c.season,
            c.content_id FROM content c
            INNER JOIN provider ON provider.id = c.provider_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN serie s ON s.seriesid = c.seriesid
            WHERE live = '0' AND c.version >= provider.version
            GROUP BY (CASE WHEN ( seriename IS NOT NULL )
            THEN seriename ELSE title END) 
            ORDER BY seriename DESC, title DESC
            LIMIT 0, 50
```

Comment: distinct it is your problem: it works so slowly! and actually you dont have index on _seriename and title_ field as i see

Comment: Did you change the query? Or did it just got slow someday.

Comment: Why do you do a `DISTINCT`on 19 columns, are there actual duplicates? And why is there that stupid LIMIT?

Comment: @N.Molderf, i do have index on seriename and title, any clue why their not used?
juergend, nothing changed actually, i mean it :/
dnoeth, i will rethink the use of distinct. And the LIMIT is because i want to output ALL the rows, not just 0,30 or 0,1000... I read that 1844... is the MAX, therefore i used it

Comment: If you want to return all rows you simply omit the `LIMIT`

Comment: Please check second last comment in my answer. I was waiting for your reply. If that worked let me know. If not please share at least explain query after making that index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the load of the server and size of the data-set requested time can vary.

I'm not sure but it sometimes makes a difference bring `c.version >= provider.version` along with join instead of in `WHERE`. Please see the complete query below. Let me know about the `EXPLAIN` result.

```
SELECT distinct(season) as seasons,
    s.name as seriename,
    c.content_digest,
    c.sub_category_id,
    c.source_url,
    c.synopsis,
    c.short_synopsis,
    c.title,
    c.duration,
    c.subtitle_url,
    c.logo_url,
    c.provider_id,
    c.event_date,
    c.start_time,
    c.live,
    c.seriesid as cSerieId,
    c.episode,
    c.season,
    c.content_id FROM content c
    INNER JOIN provider ON provider.id = c.provider_id 
    AND c.version >= provider.version
    LEFT OUTER JOIN serie s ON s.seriesid = c.seriesid
    WHERE live = '0' 
    ORDER BY seriename DESC, title
    DESC
    LIMIT 0, 18446744073709551615;
```

Also create composite(multicolumn) index of `(version, live, id)` columns in `content` table. Here is the query to create the multi-column index:
`ALTER TABLE content ADD INDEX idxc_vr_lv_id (version, live, id);`

Comment: # id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'provider', 'index', 'PRIMARY,provider_id_idx,provider_version_idx', 'provider_version_idx', '5', NULL, '16', 'Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'c', 'ref', 'c_providerid_idx,c_live_idx,c_version_idx', 'c_providerid_idx', '5', 'provider.id', '3695', 'Using where'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 's', 'ref', 'seriesid_idx', 'seriesid_idx', '97', 'c.seriesid', '1', ''

Dont think it changed specifically

Comment: Which table has `live` column? As it's not clear from the query.

Comment: "c.live", content as c

Comment: Okay take c.live to join condition as well instead of keeping it in where clause. After that again post explain.

Comment: This will surelly improve performance create a composite index of `(version, live, id)` columns.

Comment: Hello again, during the weekend i have somewhat rewritten the sql-query, your solution might have worked, but live = 0 is a variable from PHP, its not a constant, so i cant use it for composite index because next time "live=0" may not be in the query.

Sorry for not responding to quickly.

Comment: That doesn't matter if the `live`'s value is being set from PHP. The only point is that it should be a column of `content` table. If you can do it and mention the `EXPLAIN` here I'll really be thankful. You may get more quick query from what you've changed :)

Comment: could you show example how to add the composite index??

Comment: Sure! execute this query in you phpMyAdmin or MySql console after selecting the required database: `ALTER TABLE content ADD INDEX idxc_vr_lv_id (version, live, id);`

Comment: Thanks alot @Imran, the query has went from 2.5 seconds to 1.03 seconds, and now the 1st query takes 0.93 seconds and the second (cached) takes 0.0102 s. Thanks alot!

Comment: Thanks please accept the answer if it worked. And share `EXPLAIN` result as well.